# Magento xml datafeed help

Tags: xml, parsing, magento, export-to-csv, datafeed

I'm trying to import an xml datafeed of products in magento. Try importing it but is seems it has to been in MSOffice-xml or cvs file to succesfully import it. I try parsing the xml file to cvs, but was only able to parse a section of the xml file. I was only able to parse everything but the NUTRIENTS section. I use the xml2cvs code found on stackoverflow. Any suggestion of how to succesfully import this xml datafeed.

```
 <product>
<STOCK_CODE>010003</STOCK_CODE>
<UPC>705077000440</UPC>
<Basic_Description>GABA 100GM</Basic_Description>
<Brand>AST Sports Science</Brand>
<ProductLine/>
<ItemName>GABA</ItemName> 
<Title>AST Sports Science GABA</Title> 
<Flavor/>
<Supplier_Number>1</Supplier_Number>
<Supplier_Name>AST SPORTS SCIENCE</Supplier_Name>
<Primary_Category>Amino Acids</Primary_Category>
<General_Category>Supplements</General_Category>
<WHOLESALE_PRICE>17.47</WHOLESALE_PRICE>
<RETAIL_PRICE>24.95</RETAIL_PRICE>
<LIST_DATE>2004-05-12</LIST_DATE>
<DISC/>
<CLT_QOH>Yes</CLT_QOH>
<FRE_QOH>Yes</FRE_QOH>
<MES_QOH>Yes</MES_QOH>
<STR_QOH>Yes</STR_QOH>
<WND_QOH>Yes</WND_QOH>
<ORL_QOH>Yes</ORL_QOH>
<HasNutrition>1</HasNutrition>
<ValuePreparedCount>0</ValuePreparedCount>
<Address>120 Capital Drive Golden, CO 80401</Address>
<Copyright>2007 AST Sports Science, Inc.</Copyright>
<ItemSize>100</ItemSize>
<ItemMeasure>g</ItemMeasure>
<Height>4.625</Height>
<Width>2.375</Width>
<Depth>2.375</Depth>
<ProductWeight/>
<MASS>0.313</MASS>
<ExtendedSize>100 g (3.53 oz)</ExtendedSize>
<CASE_QUANTITY>12</CASE_QUANTITY>
<Description>GABA, Growth Hormone Potentiator</Description>
<ProductDetails>GABA is an amino acid classified as a neurotransmitter. Studies have shown GABA to play a key role in the secretion of Growth Hormone. The principle anabolic actions of Growth Hormone including the stimulation of amino acid transport, simulation of protein synthesis reduction of body-fat and the proliferation of cell growth. AST Sports Science selectively imports GABA under rigid quality control conditions. Each batch is HPLC Certified and Laboratory Tested for purity and potency. GABA is a naturally occurring amino acid classified as a neurotransmitter. Some individuals may experience a minor tingling of skin and/ or slight shortness of breath shortly after taking GABA. This is characteristic of this amino acid and quickly subsides.</ProductDetails>
<Directions>For adults only. As a dietary supplement, take three to five grams mixed with 8 ounce of water, juice or protein shake approximately 30 minutes before sleep.</Directions>
<Ingredients/>
<DrugInteractions/>
<Warnings/>
<PostDate>2009-08-25</PostDate>
<HTML>http://www.ast-ss.com</HTML>
  <thumbnail_url>https://secure.europadatafeed.com/images/50/705077000440.gif</thumbnail_url>
  <image_url>https://secure.europadatafeed.com/images/250/705077000440.jpg</image_url>
  <logo_url>https://secure.europadatafeed.com/images/logos/ast.gif</logo_url>
<image500_URL>https://secure.europadatafeed.com/images/500/705077000440.jpg</image500_URL>
<MAP_Price/> 
<image_name>705077000440</image_name>
<image100_URL>https://secure.europadatafeed.com/images/100/705077000440.jpg</image100_URL>

<SEA_QOH>No</SEA_QOH>



    <NUTRIENTS>

  <Nutrient>
    <AddedItem/> 
    <ISORCONTAINS>0</ISORCONTAINS>
    <NAME>Gamma Aminobutyric Acid</NAME>
    <NUTRIENTMASTERID>6260</NUTRIENTMASTERID>
    <OLDVALUEPREPAREDTYPE>0</OLDVALUEPREPAREDTYPE>
    <PCT/>
    <QUANTITY>3.0</QUANTITY>
    <SERVINGSIZETEXT>3</SERVINGSIZETEXT>
    <SERVINGSIZEUOM>Scoops</SERVINGSIZEUOM>
    <SERVINGSPERCONTAINER>33</SERVINGSPERCONTAINER>
    <TYPE>1</TYPE>
    <DETAILS/>
    <UOM>g</UOM>
    <UPC>705077000440</UPC>
    <VALUEPREPAREDTYPE>0</VALUEPREPAREDTYPE>

    </Nutrient>  

</NUTRIENTS>

</product>
```

Answer (score 0):

Importing into Magento is a very tricky thing to do- it has to be almost 100% perfect to import into Magento. I suggest using XML because it easier to create and manage. CSV is old and i have had endless problems with quotes, spaeces special character endless pain in the rear.

I have been working on and off on this private project of mine but i am in the middle of moving my projects around and making new sites.

If you are interested take a look here for some enlightment.

http://code.google.com/p/magentobridge/wiki/Hello

There are videos and some tutorials that might help you.The software despite in many years of development on the sideline is quite unstable in some areas.

I would love to help you here with a simple solution.. but its just so complex and so many things go wrong.

Now a days Magento Uses an API - but setting it up is another pain..

Comment: Is there another e-commerce platform that would be better suited for this? I not yet committed to Magento.

Comment: with each platform you will run into trouble importing you data as it needs to be formatted in the correct way. Magento is one of the largest open source e-commerce sites and is highly scalable and versatile - but you need to either pay for this or know how to program it your self.  The reason i made this program is because i manage a few shops with each one having close to 5k products and my program updates them in minutes using an external feed like yours.  Where did you get that XML from?